# Should I install Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll on my production server?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, installation

I created a `WPF` project in which the dll  `"Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll"` was referenced as reference assembly (actually I dont use it, it installed by default when I referenced the `linq2db dll`).

When I install my program on production server it gives me an error message:

`Unable to install or run the application requires that assembly microsoft.data.schema.sql.unittesting version 12.0.0.0 be installed in the global assembly cache (GAC) first.`

I already deleted the `dll` from my project, rebuilt it and deployed it and I still have the same error. Any ideas?

How can I install this `.dll` in `GAC` using code?
Should I install this `.dll` in `GAC` using code?